# Problem with wifi

Tags: wireless

I've been looking here and elsewhere for a long time to fix my wireless issues.  I upgraded to Lubuntu 14.04 and my wireless stopped working. I tried a lot of things, and then it mysteriously started working again.  I later installed security upgrades and it stopped working again.

The accepted answere at this link [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do) pointed to a script to run.  The output of that script is at http://pastebin.com/B5cLYdkx.

Please help

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? The output you linked to shows you're connected to a network. Please [edit] your question and describe the symptoms.

Comment: Are you really running 12.04? The log you point to says 14.04. Looks like wifi is up but there is some authentication problem: `wlan0: deauthenticating from * by local choice (reason=3)`

Comment: Sorry, yes, 14.04.  I fixed the original post.

I am absolutely sure that the password is correct.  In fact, the wireless was working fine up until the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Comment: Also, you're correct.  It has suddenly started working again.  This is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could find a solution via google. All I did was to install the mainline-kernel. Now it is working without any problems. I downloaded the following files:

linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb
linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb
linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb

from this site: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/

Then i used this commands:

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

After a restart i had a working wlan like in 13.10